# Node.JS - JSON Web Token, updating token information

Tags: node.js, json-web-token

I'm creating a JSON Web Token like so:

```
let userId = results[0].id;
let organizationId = results[0].organization_id;
let encryptedInfo = { 
  userId: userId, 
  organizationId: organizationId,
  admin: true
};
let tokenSecret = ENV.API_SECRET;
let token = jwt.sign(encryptedInfo, tokenSecret);
```

My question is, what do I do if a user is removed as an `admin`, or if a user who isn't an `admin`, is made an `admin`?

Would I blacklist that user's `tokenId`? And if so, does that mean I need to start storing users and their `tokenId`'s in the database?

Also, if I'm blacklisting the user's `tokenId`, is it a good practice to create a specific error code for that scenario, in which if the client side receives that error code, it re-authenticates and get's a new `token`?

Comment: Don't encrypt the data which can be modified. Retrieve the details from the database with the unique details.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up realizing. Thanks for the help